# InfluxDB and Grafana - Get today date on query editor

Tags: grafana, influxdb

How do I get the start of the current day, using Grafana and InfluxDB?

I saw that Grafana uses "now/d" in the timerange to do this. But I need to get the current day in the query editor.

[image]

**I tried this but it doesn't work:**
[image]

**I also tested:**

```
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where time > now()/d group by time(1h) 
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where time > now(d) group by time(1h) 
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where time > $now/d group by time(1h) 
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where time > $now(d) group by time(1h) 
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where time > ${now/d} group by time(1h) 
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where time > ${now(d)} group by time(1h)
```

I use the time selector for others graphs on the same dashboard. What im trying to do is a label with the total of a value. Something like this:

[image]

What I need is the “today so far” option, but on my query. Thats why it needs to be independent of time selector. Something like:

```
select mean(value) from MEASUREMENT where time >= today_so_far
```

Answer (score 0):

`now/d` is only in the UI. Each datasource may have different requirement for datetime format at the end. So use global variable `__from` and format it for your specific InfluxDB need. I guess default `${__from}` (Unix millisecond epoch) will be OK for your case. See doc: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/global-variables/#from-and-to

```
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where time > ${__from} group by time(1h)
```

Anyway, I would use default `$timeFilter` macro, so from/to time conditions will be solved by that:

```
select mean(value) from MEDIDOR where $timeFilter group by time(1h)
```

Comment: Im using a "stat" graph to show the total of a value (text only). This total need to be the init hour of each day. Example: "2021-12-13 00:00:00" after "2021-12-14 00:00:00" and so on. So I cant use the timerange field. I need some variable to give me init hour of each day.. like the today() or "now/d".

Comment: * (The timerange field is used for anotther graph on the same dashboard. Thats why I cant use the timerange field).

Comment: @JoãoSoares wrong question gives you wrong answer. And I really don't know what do you need. I'm giving up.

Comment: I need a variable (or something) that gives me the start of the current day. Like "2021-12-13 00:00:00". But still, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: I think the query should provide something like that: Show me a Value that contains the sum of all readings since "Start of the day"